# Recursion gives me a sum of addends. But how can I count on Python a number of recursions in my function not using global variable?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, counter

I get a sum of all addends (x**y). But I can't count all of the recursions. Is it really without using global variable&

```
X=10
s=0
def Rec(x, y=0, counter):
    s=x**y
    print(s)
    if X-s<0:
        return s
    return s+Rec(x, y=y+1)
print(Rec(2))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use globals (hurray) you have to carry your values through:

```
# init the y, the sum and counter to 0
def Rec(x, y=0, s=0 counter=0):  
    s+=x**y    # add to sum
    print(s)
    # end of recursion, return sum and counter as tuple
    if s>X:
        return s, counter
    # recurse with y and counter one bigger then before
    return Rec(x, y+1, s, counter+1)

X=10
s=0
print(Rec(2))
```

Output:

```
1
3
7
15
(15, 3)
```

Comment: well - someone did not like it -no idea why so can't fix it